# Where to obtain the theatrical trailer for The Matrix (1999) in a 640x274 (or higher) resolution?

Tags: the-matrix

Interestingly enough, it's difficult to obtain the theatrical trailer for *The Matrix* (1999) in a 640x274 (or higher) resolution, despite the fact that plenty of 4:3 CRT screens could do 640x480 in 1999, the film received positive reviews from most critics and is widely regarded as one of the greatest science fiction films of all time.

The trailer was re-released on 19 December 2003 at whatisthematrix.warnerbros.com. However, the people who ran that website made a mistake and accidentally provided a 480x205 version where it says 640x274. You can verify this yourself by checking the contents of the .sit and .zip packages via the Internet Archive, or simply by downloading the - still available - [matrix_tr_theatrical_640.mov](http://pdl3.warnerbros.com/thematrix/us/med/matrix_tr_theatrical_640.mov) file from warnerbros.com.

On YouTube, an unofficial 720p trailer can be found, but I'm looking for the [official trailer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UM5yepZ21pI) in a 640x274 (or higher) resolution. I know it exists, because I've had it in my possession in 1999. I've used the Video DownloadHelper to inspect several trailers on YouTube, but none of these videos turned out to have the proper resolution/quality.

Comment: Maybe the 640x274 version I once had in my possession was an edited version of the 640x480 version of the trailer?

Comment: While this is a valid question, I don't think this type of question is suited for this site: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/faq